# Getting aws cloudwatch datapoints in random time order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Running the below mentioned aws cli query

```
"aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace xx --metric-name xx  --period xx --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=xx,Value=i-xx --start-time xx --end-time xx --output json"
```

I'm getting output as random order as follow -

```
 Datapoints": [
    {
        "Timestamp": "2016-07-17T19:18:00Z",
        "Maximum": 1.0,
        "Unit": "Percent"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2016-07-20T17:48:00Z",
        "Maximum": 1.8,
        "Unit": "Percent"
    },
    {
        "Timestamp": "2016-07-18T16:18:00Z",
        "Maximum": 1.33,
        "Unit": "Percent"
    },
```

Can anyone help me, to get time sorted output.
Is there any command line option available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something with jq sort_by methods (see [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/))

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace xx --metric-name xx  --period xx --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=xx,Value=i-xx --start-time xx --end-time xx --output json |\
jq '.Datapoints | sort_by(.Timestamp)'
```

This will return a new Json object sorted by the Timestamp field value

Comment: Is there any java libraries available to do the same functionality?

Comment: you can use the [aws java sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/sdk-for-java/) that you can get the [getMetrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AbstractAmazonCloudWatch.html#getMetricStatistics-com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricStatisticsRequest-) but you will need to parse from Java